# How can I present a second alert in "didSelectItemAt" method from collection view?

Tags: swift

```
override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        let person = people[indexPath.item ] // person variable will contain the person's name at a path/index/position
        
        let ac = UIAlertController(title: "Rename person", message: nil, preferredStyle: .alert)
        ac.addTextField() // adding a text field to the alert
    
        // This closure uses a weak reference cycle, weakly capturing the view controller and the alert, this closure code will be excuted only if the user provides a person name otherwise this code will return and will do nothing at all, the label text will be blank
        ac.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel)) // this a cancel button on the alert
        ac.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default) { [weak self, weak ac] _ in
            guard let newName = ac?.textFields?[0].text else { return } // if the user typed a person's name in the alert text field box, then add it to "newName" variable / if we have no text added in that field then just return
            person.name = newName // person's name is saved to "person" array this is how we store all the names
                
            
            self?.collectionView.reloadData() // collection view is reloaded so the label's default text will be replaced with the newly added/ saved person's name
        })
        
        present(ac, animated: true) // alert is presented
        
    }
    
}
```

I'm fetching some image data from disk [photo library] using `FileManager` from `documentDirectory`, using `ImagePickerController`.

So basically when I choose a picture from disk and add it to a collection view cell, first time when I click on the picture I can add a string there [here we add a person name, so basically any `String` can be added] an alert will pop up and asking to add a new person name or cancel [ I have a CANCEL and an OK button on the alert].

I want to show a second alert when I tap again on a picture that already has a name added [this string replaces the LABEL's name in that cell, so I have an imageView and a Label there basically]. I want this second alert to ask the user if it want to rename or delete the current image name.

This would be the dictionary what I get back from iOS by default:

```
func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any]) { // user has selected an image data from their camera which has acces to their photo library
    guard let image = info[.editedImage] as? UIImage else { return } // imaged is pulled out from image picker and is type casted/ if there's no image then  -> return
    
    let imageName = UUID().uuidString // new filename is created for the image what just got imported
    let imagePath = getDocumentsDirectory().appendingPathComponent(imageName) // path is created for the file [random file name, which basically is the copy of the original image which is imported] which is the new UUID filename
    
    if let jpegData = image.jpegData(compressionQuality: 0.8)  { // image is converted to a JPEG data format with a quality value of 80%
        try? jpegData.write(to: imagePath) // write JPEG data to the file name [created by UUID] which s saved to the current document directory
    }
    
    let person = Person(name: "Unknown", image: imageName)
    people.append(person)
    collectionView.reloadData()
    
    dismiss(animated: true) // view controller get dismissed
}
```

This is where I create the UUID:

override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
let person = people[indexPath.item ]

let ac = UIAlertController(title: "Rename person", message: nil, preferredStyle: .alert)
ac.addTextField()

ac.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel))
ac.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default) { [weak self, weak ac] _ in
guard let newName = ac?.textFields?[0].text else { return }
person.name = newName

self?.collectionView.reloadData()

})

present(ac, animated: true)

Comment: It seems like you'd need to keep track of a state somewhere whether each cell as been tapped or not. If not, present the first alert and if so, present the second. Seems like it could just be a dictionary with the model's ID and the tap state. But, you're not showing any of your model layer, so it's hard to tell. What have you tried so far?

Comment: @jnpdx I was thinking about that but I don't know how to keep track of that state you just mentioned as I'm just going through Paul Hudson's 100days of Swift course, I have declared the following function at the moment but I didn't figured out yet where to call this I'm still kinda struggling with it and also I think I need maybe "self.collectionView.reloadData()"  in this closure because I think this "self.people.removeAll()" is removing the image from the actual cell when I tap the "delete" button.

Comment: func showSecondAlert() {
        let ac2 = UIAlertController(title: "Do you want to rename or delete the current person name?", message: nil, preferredStyle: .alert)
        ac2.addTextField()
        
        ac2.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel))
        ac2.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Delete", style: .destructive) { _ in
            self.people.removeAll()
            
            self.collectionView.reloadData()
        })
        
        present(ac2, animated: true)
    
      }

Comment: Does `Person` have an id? Maybe a `UUID`? An overly-simplistic version would be to make a dictionary of type `[UUID:Int]` that stores the `id` of the `Person` and the number of taps that it has had. Would you know how to add that? And how to increment the number once a user has tapped it?

Comment: @jnpdx I create the UUID here: let imageName = UUID().uuidString 
   let imagePath=getDocumentsDirectory().appendingPathComponent(imageName),

Comment: if let jpegData = image.jpegData(compressionQuality: 0.8)  {
            try? jpegData.write(to: imagePath)         }

Comment: @jnpdx I don't use any particular ID I have a custom class "Person" which has two properties var name: String and var image: String

Comment: Your `Person` model should probably have a UUID so that you can differentiate them. Then you can try the dictionary idea I mentioned.

Comment: @jnpdx this is what I have here let person = Person(name: "Unknown", image: imageName)
        people.append(person)
        collectionView.reloadData()

Comment: @jnpdx not really sure how i can do that I'm bit confused to be honest

Comment: @jnpdx the "imageName" property will have that UUID than that is added to "Person" class "image" property, I have an array called "people" type String which will hold  this   let person = Person(name: "Unknown", image: imageName)
        people.append(person)
        collectionView.reloadData()

Comment: Put a `var id = UUID()` on your `Person` model. Then, you don't even need to store an `imageName` property -- it'll just be `"\(id).jpg"` (or whatever you name it). Then, make a variable on your view controller like `var tapState = [UUID:Int]` where you can store how many taps have occurred for a given `UUID`

Comment: @jnpdx I will try it, thank you!

Comment: @jnpdx just one quick question, my Person model has an  "init()" I just added  the "id" property to it as well

Comment: I'm not seeing a question there. I'd assume you'd want `Person` to be a `struct` -- I don't have access to any of your code, so I'm not sure why/if you need a custom `init`. My guess is this would be enough: `struct Person { var id = UUID(); var name : String }`

Comment: @jnpdx "Person" is a custom class with an init()

Comment: @jnpdx is this one:           class Person: NSObject {
    var name: String
    var image: String
    
    
    init(name: String, image: String) {
        self.name = name
        self.image = image
    }
}

Comment: Okay. You can still just put in `var id = UUID` in your property definitions.

Comment: @jnpdx is giving me an error here let imagePath = getDocumentsDirectory().appendingPathComponent("\(id)") at this line sayin "id" is unavailable in Swift and is telling me to use "Any"

Comment: @jnpdx I have this now in my Person class 
class Person: NSObject {
    var name: String
    var image: String
    var id = UUID().uuidString
    
    
    init(name: String, image: String, id: String) {
        self.name = name
        self.image = image
        self.id = id
        
        
    }
}

Comment: Sorry, this isn't a good format for going back and forth like this with so many different problems. I'll say that it should be more something like `.appendingPathComponent("\(person.id).jpg")` assuming `person` is the name of your `Person` instance. Good luck!

Comment: @jnpdx   let person = people[indexPath.item ] // person variable will contain the person's name at a path/index/position